# Do not make values in the SQL table from php code

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

Sorry for the stupid question. Do not make values in the table from php code 
Only from phpmyadmin. While able to read records from a table. What could be the problem? 
User is same, has all privileges.

My code. Table contain id, site name, ip of the site.

```
$host='localhost'; 
$database='Spider';
$user='myuser';
$pswd='mypassword';
$dbh = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pswd) or die("Не могу соединиться с MySQL.");
mysql_select_db($database) or die("Не могу подключиться к базе.");
$query = "SELECT id, site, ip FROM `sites` LIMIT 0,100";
$res = mysql_query($query);
$reverse_ip = array();
for ($i=1; $row=mysql_fetch_array($res); $i++) {
    echo $row['site']."<br>"; //print site name
    $reverse_ip[$i] = substr($row['site'], 7, strlen($row['site'])-7);
    if (strpos($reverse_ip[$i], 'www.') !== false) {
        $reverse_ip[$i] = substr($reverse_ip[$i], 4, strlen($reverse_ip[$i])-4);
    }
    if (strpos($reverse_ip[$i], '/')) {
        $reverse_ip[$i] = substr($reverse_ip[$i], 0, -1); //editing site name
    }
    echo $reverse_ip[$i]."<br>"; //print the edited name
    $reverse_ip[$i]=gethostbyname($reverse_ip[$i]);
    echo $reverse_ip[$i]."<br>"; //print the ip of site
}
$sql = "UPDATE sites SET ip = 200 WHERE id = 4 "; //table remains unchanged
```

When I When I use this  queries `$sql = "UPDATE sites SET ip = 200 WHERE id = 4 ";` in phpmyadmin it works

Comment: The problem is likely your code, which you haven't provided.

Comment: It is unlikely, because the same code in phpmyadmin correctly performs all.

Comment: @Hushpar Post your code so we can help you.

Comment: For example:
$sql = "UPDATE sites SET ip = 200 WHERE id = 4 "

Comment: @Hushpar That phpMyAdmin works and your code doesn't makes it nearly certain you messed something up. If you won't show code, we can't help you. Not your **queries**, your **code**.

Comment: @ceejayoz sorry. Added code to the head post.

Comment: @Hushpar See why we ask for code? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `$res = mysql_query($query); $res` isn't valid syntax.

After your `mysql_query` lines, do `echo mysql_error();` and see what it says. Once you've figured out the immediate issue, go to http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php, read the big red box, and stop using the `mysql_*` functions at all.

Your line:

```
$sql = "UPDATE sites SET ip = 200 WHERE id = 4 "; //table remains unchanged
```

doesn't update the database. It's a SQL query, but you aren't executing it anywhere.

Comment: did echo mysql_error(); but it printed me nothing.
OK, thx very much.

Comment: If it prints nothing, there wasn't an error. I suspect the last bit - you're building a query, but not executing it - is the fundamental issue.